# evince crashes when I try to open some pdf

Tags: pdf, evince

When I try to open one of my pdf files with evince, it will crash with exit code 134 and this message prints out:

```
! SyncTeX Error : No file?
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also, downgrading evince won't work.
I'm able to open that pdf on the earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Also to note: I'm using Ubuntu devel branch.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug that was [fixed in poppler 0.72.0-1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242607).  As a workaround to updating, okular works for me.